# Charging 18650 pack with solar

Tags: voltage, power, batteries, solar-cell, charging

I am trying to charge a 18650 pack with a solar panel. What is the best way to control each cell's voltage ? Is it a problem to charge them with a constant voltage and **unstable current** . Our current starts from 0 and rises to top at noon and it will decreases to the zero again. It is impossible to make a stable and constant current with solar controller or mppt. How can i solve this unstable current problem or do i have to solve it? What will happen if i charge them with a unstable current.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. You need to provide some schematics, or more refined design hints in order to show some work from where people can help you. Otherwise, your question can end up being closed as either "too broad" or "not having enough research effort".

Answer (score 6):

> What is the best way to control each cell's voltage ?

You will need to balance your pack, ie ensure all cells reach the same voltage, and prevent overcharge and overdischarge of the weakest cell.

This usually involves sensing the voltage on each cell independently (using an instrumentation amplifier, for instance) and also a way to individually discharge the strongest cells.

Every laptop battery pack includes one of these battery management systems. This means chip manufacturers have plenty of ready-made, industry-proven solutions.

Under and over voltage limits are per cell, and they are **not negotiable**. Overdischarge will destroy your cells, and then when you attempt to charge them, things will happen. And don't forget the temperature sensor!

Don't design your own! Check Linear Tech, etc.

> Is it a problem to charge them with a constant voltage and unstable current

This is **not a problem at all** as Li batteries have no "memory effect".

All you need to do is know precisely the maximum current and voltage your battery will tolerate. Design a voltage-limited current source (or a current-limited voltage source, which is the same). Set the emphasis on voltage precision.

And whenever you have power... activate your charger. That's it.

I did research on this for a bicycle "dynamo" light. The hum "dynamo" (actually an alternator) provides a few watts, but only if the bicycle is going fast enough. Obviously then, available power is intermittent, unless the rider runs ALL the red lights!

I was surprised at how easy LiIon batteries were to manage... Yes, you can really use them like big capacitors, charge them when you have energy and discharge them when you need energy.

I asked a buddy who is a specialist (he designs EV batteries for a reputable manufacturer) and got confirmation for this. There is no problem. They use that for regen braking, etc.

Your battery has a lifetime specified as a certain number of full charge cycles. The great thing is that microcycles (ie, charging the battery a little, then discharging a little, then repeat) work exactly as you expect, ie, if you do charge/discharge cycles using 10% of capacity, then you will need 10 of those microcycles to equate the aging caused by a full cycle.

Now, there is a catch: if your equipment is in a remote location, you will most likely want to use a max charge voltage 0.05 to 0.1V lower than the max cell voltage. Reasons are:

- This will prolong LiIon cell life. Perhaps add more battery capacity too. That depends if the guy who's gonna come with a ladder to change the batteries costs more than a few extra cells!
- You need to be absolutely sure you don't float charge at max charge voltage like you'd do with lead acid. Let's say it is 4V2. You charge the cells to 4V2, all is fine. Now, a cloud casts a shadow over your solar cell. It stops charging for five minutes, and your device draws current instead. The cloud goes away. Due to hysteresis in your cells, the cell voltage will **appear** to be, say, 4.15V so the charger happily resumes charging... but the battery is actually fully charged, and it will vehemently disagree with such treatment. So, shave 50-100 mV off your CV limit unless your battery manufacturer signs you a waiver.

Mains-powered chargers include timers to guard against this. If you lose the last 100mV, you only lose very little mAh capacity. Check your discharge curves. I used 4.05V on 4.2V LiIon. Works like a charm!

> It is impossible to make a stable and constant current with solar controller or mppt. How can i solve this unstable current problem or do i have to solve it? What will happen if i charge them with a unstable current.

As I said, nothing bad happens at all.

In order to conserve power, the scheme I used was a switching constant current source, set to the CC charging current, and optimized for efficiency at that current.

This was switched one and off via PWM by a uC. PWM duty cycle was set according to cell voltage, to emulate the current tapering off during the CV phase. It works very well.

A temperature sensor is mandatory, don't forget it! LiIon gets angry if you charge it outside of temperature limits...

Comment: Mention the absolute prohibition of continuing to float charge at max voltage, and the strict under- and over-voltage limits, and I'll upvote this answer.

Comment: Done. I just remembered I used 4.05V float limit in my implementation for this very reason.

Comment: Good answer - better than most on this topic. I was going to provide a brief answer and point to a few of my prior ones, but your answer covers the main points. | Reducing Vmax to 4.05V lightly reduces per cycle capacity, and increases whole of life cycles with an overall gain in total provided capacity over lifetime. If doing a similar project again consider LiFePO4. They give much longer lifetime cycles. They can be CCCV charged like std LiIon or you can take advantage of their strange rapid rise of voltage at full capacity (3.6V to <= 4.2V) to use CC only charging.

Comment: With solar it is better to use a Maximum Power Point Tracking (MPPT) rather than PWM.